# Retrieve submitted form's ID and/or Name with jQuery .submit()

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery

I've loaded few forms using .load() to different DIVs. The loaded file looks like the following example.

```
<div id="block_id-299">
  <div id="content">
    <form name="form1" method="post">
      <input type="submit" name="field1" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

And now I am trying to retrieve submitted form's name and later, it's values using `.serialize()`. 
I was using `$('form').submit(function(){ ... }` but since I am loading the form dynamically, this does not work anymore.

Any help?

PS: The event can be catched using `$(document).submit(function(){` but how to get form's name and/or ID?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this with $().delegate:

```
$(document).delegate('form', 'submit', function(event) {
    var $form = $(this);
    var id = $form.attr('id');
    var data = $form.serialize();
    // ...
});
```

This works even on forms added after you called delegate().

This works by listening for `submit` events the bubbled up to `document`, and by testing if the even originates from a `form` element.

This is similar to `$('form').live('click', ...)`, but doesn't initially executes the selector.

See [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) and [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live) documentation.

Comment: Is there a way to get the submitted button's name and value also?

Comment: Try `$(document).delegate('form button, form submit', 'click', ...`

Answer (score 1):

To get the form attributes while submitting form, we can also get using the [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) function. For example:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
  var form = $(this);
  var id = form.attr('id');
  alert(id + ' form submitted');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery` [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event handler which work for dynamically created elements also.
Try this

```
$('form').live('submit', function(event) {
    var $form = $(this);
    var formName = $form.attr('name');
    var formData = $form.serialize();
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will alert the form id of the button having 'create_btn' css, you can also access it by id if you want by changing the (.create-btn)dot to hash(#create-btn) and you can use .click or .submit instead.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $('.create-btn').click(function(){
      alert(this.form.id);

       }) ;

  });
```